# Does Mahabharata say that Gokarna darshan can give moksha?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, moksha, pilgrimage

In Telugu translation of the last slokhas of [this](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01220.htm) section, it has been said that the darshan of Gokarna can give moksha.

But it is not present in the English translation (in the link I provided above). It is only saying that Arjuna proceeded towards Gokarna.

But, does Mahabharata anywhere say that Gokarna Darshan can give Moksha?